# Ponctuation, guillemet à gauche mais pas à droite

Tags: ponctuation

La ponctuation suivante n'est pas habituelle ; je n'en ai jamais lu un exemple, sauf dans une édition du livre  *La Peste*, d'Albert Camus. Les paragraphes commencent par un guillemet français mais ne se terminent pas par le second guillemet. Il y a quatre ou cinq paragraphes de cette sorte à la suite les uns des autres. À l'intérieur des paragraphes les guillemets anglais sont utilisés.

Est-ce que cela a une signification particulière ?  Est-ce la ponctuation personnelle de Camus ? Dans une autre édition du même livre la ponctuation est normale, le guillemet final est utilisé.

> Puis il entamait sa description :
> « Au petit matin, des souffles légers parcourent la ville
> encore déserte. À cette heure, qui est entre les morts de
> la nuit et les agonies de la journée, il semble que la peste
> suspende un instant son effort et reprenne son souffle.
> Toutes les boutiques sont fermées. Mais sur quelques-unes, l’écriteau “Fermé pour cause de peste” atteste
> qu’elles n’ouvriront pas tout à l’heure avec les autres. Des
> vendeurs de journaux encore endormis ne crient pas les
> nouvelles, mais, adossés au coin des rues, offrent leur
> marchandise aux réverbères dans un geste de
> somnambules. Tout à l’heure, réveillés par les premiers
> tramways, ils se répandront dans toute la ville, tendant à
> bout de bras les feuilles où éclate le mot “Peste ”. “Y aura-
> t-il un automne de peste ? Le professeur B… répond :
> Non.” “Cent vingt-quatre morts, tel est le bilan de la
> quatre-vingt-quatorzième journée de peste.”
> « Malgré la crise du papier qui devient de plus en plus
> aiguë et qui a forcé certains périodiques à diminuer le
> nombre de leurs pages, il s’était créé un autre journal : le
> Courrier
> de
> l’Épidémie, qui se donne pour tâche
> d’“informer nos concitoyens, dans un souci de scrupuleuse
> objectivité, des progrès ou des reculs de la maladie ; de
> leur fournir les témoignages les plus autorisés sur l’avenir
> de l’épidémie ; de prêter l’appui de ses colonnes à tous
> ceux, connus ou inconnus, qui sont disposés à lutter
> contre le fléau ; de soutenir le moral de la population, de
> transmettre les directives des autorités et, en un mot, de
> grouper toutes les bonnes volontés pour lutter
> efficacement contre le mal qui nous frappe”. En réalité, ce
> journal s’est borné très rapidement à publier des
> annonces de nouveaux produits, infaillibles pour prévenir
> la peste.
> […]

Comment: … fin du dernier des paragraphes **»** des § commençant par **«** — ceci, afin clore l'incise — ; on peut aussi mettre ce type de guillemets devant chaque ligne du paragraphe qui relate un dit hors contexte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En typographie traditionnelle Française, lorsqu'une citation contient plusieurs paragraphes, chaque paragraphe commence par un guillemet. Suivant les éditeurs, ce peut être un guillemet ouvrant ou un guillemet fermant. Dans les deux cas, ce guillemet de début de paragraphe n'a pas de guillemet symétrique correspondant. Plus minoritairement, certains éditeurs mettent un guillemet au début de chaque ligne de la citation.

C'est encore vrai aujourd'hui pour des mises en page de textes plus anciens, mais moins pour des textes modernes, à mon avis parce que les textes modernes ont moins tendance à contenir des citations de plusieurs paragraphes. En fiction, on a plus tendance à utiliser un style indirect avec le point de vue d'un personnage. En non-fiction, on a plus tendance à utiliser un exergue ou une section avec un préambule et une note entre parenthèses à la fin pour citer un texte d'un auteur différent, sans ponctuation particulière. Une citation longue est souvent en italiques.

Dans tous les cas, si la citation commence par un guillemet, elle devrait se terminer par le guillemet symétrique.

Pour ce qui est des citations à l'intérieur de citations, on utilise en général les guillemets à doubles chevrons habituels (« citation « interne » externe »), mais on trouve aussi des guillemets anglais doubles (« citation “interne” externe »).

Sauf rare exception, ce sont des choix de l'imprimeur ou à la rigueur de l'éditeur, pas de l'auteur.

La [typographie Québecoise](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect7&info0=7.2.5) a conservé les mêmes usages. En revanche, les usages Belges et Suisses, même francophones, sont à ma connaissance plus variables et plus proches respectivement des usages néerlandophones et germanophones.